# Angular2 and Karma Run only one test suite aka describe.only

Tags: javascript, testing, angular, jasmine, karma-runner

This does not seem to work with Karma and Angular2.

```
describe.only("MyComp"), () => {
...
```

Any ideas how to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`describe.only` is how exclusive/focused tests are marked in Mocha, not Jasmine.

In Jasmine, [focused tests](http://jasmine.github.io/2.1/focused_specs.html) are achieved via `fdescribe` and `fit`.

Comment: Great! Thanks man. Just found it in the docs myself. Confirmed working.

Comment: Its still not working